# How to show if rhomobile array is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhomobile

I have a bit of code in RhoMobile that shows results of a search.  I want to display a message if no results are found but as a Ruby n00b I'm not getting the message I want output.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
   <% @employees.each do |employee| %>

     <li>
       <a href="<%= url_for :action => :show, :id => employee.object %>">
         <%= employee.name %>
       </a>
     </li>

   <% end %>
   <% "<li>No results found</li>" if @employees.empty? %>
</ul>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What are you getting as output? Please also check the HTML source directly.

Comment: When there are no results I'm not getting 'No results found' as a list item.  Just <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview"></ul>

Comment: As it is on a mobile device in a private browser that is a bit tricky to get hold of, the inspector shows an empty <ul>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `=`, it should be:

```
<%= "<li>No results found</li>" if @employees.empty? %>
```

Though that might not work either because the string isn't marked as HTML safe. That said, it's probably best to wrap everything in a conditional to make it more clear and avoid having HTML in a string:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <% if @employees.any? %>
    <% @employees.each do |employee| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to employee.name, {:action => :show, :id => employee.object} %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <li>No results found</li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I've also replaced your hand-coded link with a call to [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: This code worked with the link, your link_to did not get any where on rhoMobile.  <%= link_to employee.name, {:action => :show, :id => employee.object} %>

Comment: @Martlark Well you tagged your question as Rails, and `link_to` will work in Rails. I really know much about Rhombile, but if it doesn't use Rails underneath than you should retag your question.

Comment: It does use ruby on rails.  And modifying the link_to in your code as in my comment makes it work.

Comment: Well the way I had it should work, even in Rails 2.3 (and perhaps earlier), unless you're not using RESTful routes for some reason.